# Hiding _source fields based on other fields

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, filter

Let's say I have two documents in a Elasticsearch index:

```
[
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 2,
        "visible_fields": ["foo"]
    },
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 2,
        "visible_fields": ["bar"]
    }
]
```

I want only the fields listed in `visible_fields` for each document to be returned in a query response. How would I do that?

I'm thinking a custom plugin or script could solve it but I don't know how or where to start. Looking through the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins) for the existing plugins I can't find anything that I can use to access and modify the `_source` fields.

Comment: You need to use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-source-filtering.html).

Comment: @slawek How would you use that to read from `visible_fields`?